# ASP.NET ERROR: SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

First of all I have to take obvious things out of the way; I have searched for the same problem, there is an answer to this question on StackOverFlow but it didn't worked for me.

**Problem:** I am getting an error

> SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size

on the line with this statement

```
cmd.Prepare();
```

DB schema:

[image]

Code:

```
//alreadyAnsweredQues is Global -- List<Int32>
var parameters = new string[alreadyAnsweredQues.Count];
var cmd = new SqlCommand();

for (int i = 0; i < alreadyAnsweredQues.Count; i++)
{
    parameters[i] = string.Format("@qid{0}", i);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameters[i].ToString(), SqlDbType.Int).Value = alreadyAnsweredQues[i];
}

cmd.Parameters.Add("@cid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Session["c_id"].ToString());

cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM questions WHERE c_id = @cid AND q_id NOT IN ({0}) ORDER BY NEWID() ;", string.Join(", ", parameters));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM questions WHERE c_id = @cid AND q_id NOT IN ({0}) ORDER BY NEWID() ;", string.Join(", ", parameters)));

cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionClass.constr);
cmd.Connection.Open();

cmd.Prepare();

SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < alreadyAnsweredQues.Count; i++)
{
    parameters[i] = string.Format("@qid{0}", i);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameters[i].ToString(), SqlDbType.Int).Value = alreadyAnsweredQues[i];
}

cmd.Parameters.Add("@cid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Session["c_id"].ToString());
```

should be changed to:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Session["c_id"].ToString());

for (int i = 0; i < alreadyAnsweredQues.Count; i++)
{
    parameters[i] = string.Format("@qid{0}", i);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameters[i].ToString(), SqlDbType.Int).Value = alreadyAnsweredQues[i];
}
```

There is no need to specify a `Size` for an `int` since it has a fixed (4 byte) size.

I would also recommend you comment out:

```
cmd.Prepare();
```

since there is [minimal benefit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175528.aspx):

> In SQL Server, the prepare/execute model has no significant
>   performance advantage over direct execution, because of the way SQL
>   Server reuses execution plans

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the SqlParameter.Size property on each parameter object.

Comment: could you please explain a little bit more ..?

Comment: This is unnecessary for `int` parameters.

Answer (score -1):

As @SoronelHaetir asked in his answer that

> You need to set the SqlParameter.Size property on each parameter object.

After that the problem was that I didn't knew the size of the integer that was going to database, so what I did was that I put `System.Int32.MaxValue` and it worked fine.

Code:

```
var parameters = new string[alreadyAnsweredQues.Count];
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
for (int i = 0; i < alreadyAnsweredQues.Count; i++)
{
    parameters[i] = string.Format("@qid{0}", i);


    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameters[i].ToString(), SqlDbType.Int,System.Int32.MaxValue).Value = alreadyAnsweredQues[i];
}


cmd.Parameters.Add("@cid", SqlDbType.Int, System.Int32.MaxValue).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Session["c_id"].ToString());



cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM questions WHERE c_id = @cid AND q_id NOT IN ({0}) ORDER BY NEWID() ;", string.Join(", ", parameters));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM questions WHERE c_id = @cid AND q_id NOT IN ({0}) ORDER BY NEWID() ;", string.Join(", ", parameters)));
cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionClass.constr);
cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.Prepare();
```

P.S: This might not be the best way to handle this, but it worked for me.

Comment: If the values are ints, why are you sending them as varchar? You should change to SqlDbType.Int like you do for the @cid parameter (which should also allow you to remove the size component, though I believe "4" would be the correct value if you must pass it).

Comment: `System.Int32.MaxValue` Size is **not** the same thing as MaxValue.

Comment: @mjwills, Actually this code is inside a function, and this function is executed at least 10 times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161894/discussion-between-zakawat-and-mjwills).